# « Il faut que je vous déçoive »

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques, néerlandais

En néerlandais il y a une tournure qui se traduit mot à mot comme suit:
« Il faut que je vous déçoive » (Ou peut-être plutôt « déçois ».)
Je dessine un cadre auquel la tournure s’applique :

Quelqu’un vient à une boutique pour y acheter telle ou telle chose, mais malheureusement cette denrée n’appartient plus à la gamme. Le commerçant dit « Il faut que je vous déçoive, on n’en a plus. »
Autrement dit, les circonstances « contraignent » quelqu’un de décevoir une autre personne : Il n’y a pas de moyen pour la contenter, et dit ainsi poliment qu’il ne peut pas l’aider.

Je voudrais savoir ce qu’un français pense s’il entend « qu’il faut qu’on le déçoive. » J’ai peur qu’il pense que son interlocuteur ait pour dessein de l'énerver, qu’il veut dire « Je vous prive de ce que vous souhaitez afin de vous embêter. » Cela m’empêche bien sur de m’exprimer comme ça en français.

Qu’en pensez-vous ? Est-ce qu’on doit éviter une telle phrase, ou serait-elle facilement saisie ? Au deuxième cas, pourriez-vous me donner une meilleure tournure que « Je suis désolé, je ne peux pas vous aider » ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Une autre formulation serait « J'ai (bien) peur de vous décevoir, mais… »

Comment: Y-a-t-il une raison pour le « -1 » ? Si je ne l’avais pas vu, cette réponse me satisferait peut-être. Y-a-til quelqu’un qui trouve que ceci est une tournure mal choisie ?

Comment: Pas du tout, je ne comprends pas non plus le -1. Je parle français de naissance et c'est la tournure que j'aurais utilisée. Elle est un peu plus au registre familier que ce qui est proposé par M42, mais tout à fait acceptable.

Comment: @KoenraadvanDuin Non seulement acceptable mais assez courante, avec sa variante : « je crains fort de ... » (craindre et avoir peur sont quasi synonymes). + 1

Answer (score 4):

Comme tu le supposes, « il faut qu’on le déçoive » introduit une notion de volonté de décevoir, ce qui n'est manifestement pas agréable à entendre et qui est donc à éviter.

Tu pourrais utiliser la formulation : « Je suis au regret de vous décevoir mais je n'ai plus cet article. »

Comment: Variante : « Je crains fort de vous décevoir, mais... »